# Read random files from assets on Android

Tags: android, arrays, image, assets

Hello I'm having problem reading random files on Eclipse, Android programming...
At assets folders I have a folder called "fytyra" and there are jpg pictures with mumbers like 1.jpg 2.jpg...

I tried to debug the app, list was null always.. ???

//Gets a random number from 0 to 431,.. I think it is !

```
private int nasiqim (){
        int i = 0;
        Random nasiqimi = new Random();
        i=nasiqimi.nextInt(431);
        return i;
    }
```

//This need to fill list with integers and to not repeat the same number...

```
private void listaEFotove(){
        int nse=-1,i=0,numriRandom;


        while (nse<0){
            numriRandom = nasiqim();
            nse = Arrays.binarySearch(numrat, numriRandom);
            if (nse <0 ){
                numrat[i] = numriRandom;
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 11)break;
        }
        }
```

This is to fill imageView with photos...

```
private void merrFytyrat(){
int fotoNr=0;
    String emri;
    listaEFotove();

        for (int i=0; i<11;i++){
        fotoNr=numrat[i];

        if (i==0){
            try 
        {
            emri = Integer.toString(fotoNr);
            // get input stream
            InputStream ims = getAssets().open( "fytyra/" + emri +".jpg");
            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
            // set image to ImageView
            i11.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) 
        {
            return;
        };
        }
        else if (i==1){ ... Continues until 12...
```

Comment: Now tell what goes wrong and your questions(s) please. Any catches?

Comment: `getAssets().open( "/fytyra/" + emri +".jpg");`. Not shure if that should be `getAssets().open( "fytyra/" + emri +".jpg");`. Please try.

Comment: it catches exception at this line :
'nse = Arrays.binarySearch(numrat, numriRandom);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, thank you greenapps, for trying to help mee...
My mistake was on declaration of array... so my new code is this :

```
int[] numrat = new int[12];
```

it was like this :

```
int[] numrat = null;
```

another mistake was on the getAssets, like greenapps told me

```
getAssets().open( "/fytyra/" + emri +".jpg");
```

now thanks to him i changed that code to :

```
getAssets().open( "fytyra/" + emri +".jpg");
```

No everything works perfect,.,
This site is the best, Thank you...